# Bad Result And Evaluation From Giza++

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, moses, giza++

I have tried to work with giza++ on window (using Cygwin compiler).
I used this code:

//Suppose source language is French and target language is English

```
plain2snt.out  FrenchCorpus.f  EnglishCorpus.e

mkcls  -c30  -n20  -pFrenchCorpus.f  -VFrenchCorpus.f.vcb.classes  opt
mkcls  -c30  -n20  -pEnglishCorpus.e  -VEnglishCorpus.e.vcb.classes  opt
snt2cooc.out  FrenchCorpus.f.vcb  EnglishCorpus.e.vcb  FrenchCorpus.f_EnglishCorpus.e.snt >courpuscooc.cooc

GIZA++  -S  FrenchCorpus.f.vcb  -T EnglishCorpus.e.vcb -C FrenchCorpus.f_EnglishCorpus.e.snt  -m1 100  -m2 30  -mh 30  -m3 30  -m4 30  -m5 30  -p1 o.95  -CoocurrenceFile  courpuscooc.cooc -o     dictionary
```

But the  after getting the output files from giza++  and evaluate output, I observed that the results were too bad.

My evaluation result  was:

RECALL =    0.0889

PRECISION = 0.0990

F_MEASURE = 0.0937

AER =       0.9035

Dose any body know the reason? Could the reason be that I have forgotten some parameters or I should change some of them?

in other word:

first I wanted train giza++ by huge amount of data and then test it by small corpus and compare its result by desired alignment(GOLD STANDARD) , but I don't find any document or useful page in web.

can you introduce useful document?

Therefore I ran it by small courpus (447 sentence) and compared result by desired alignment.do you think this is right way?

Also I changed my code as follows and got better result but It's still not good:

GIZA++  -S testlowsf.f.vcb  -T testlowde.e.vcb  -C testlowsf.f_testlowde.e.snt  -m1 5  -m2 0  -mh 5  -m3 5  -m4 0  -CoocurrenceFile inputcooc.cooc  -o dictionary -model1dumpfrequency 1  -model4smoothfactor 0.4  -nodumps 0  -nsmooth 4  -onlyaldumps 1  -p0 0.999 -diagonal yes  -final yes

result of evaluation :

// suppose A is result of GIZA++ and G is Gold standard. As and Gs is S link in A And G files. Ap and Gp is p link in A and G files.

RECALL = As intersect Gs/Gs = 0.6295

PRECISION = Ap intersect Gp/A = 0.1090

FMEASURE = (2*PRECISION*RECALL)/(RECALL + PRECISION) = 0.1859

AER = 1 - ((As intersect Gs + Ap intersect Gp)/(A + S)) = 0.7425

Do you know the reason?

Answer (score 1):

Where did you get those parameters? 100 iterations of model1?! Well, if you actually manage to run this, I strongly suspect that you have a **very** small parallel corpus. If so, you should consider adding more parallel data in training. And how exactly do you calculate the recall and precision measures?

**EDIT:**

With less than 500 sentences you're unlikely to get any reasonable performance. The usual way to do it is not find a larger (unaligned) parallel corpus, run GIZA++ on both together and then evaluate the small part for which you have the manual alignments. Check [Europarl](http://www.statmt.org/europarl/) or [MultiUN](http://www.euromatrixplus.net/multi-un/), these are freely available corpora, both contain a relatively large amount of English-French parallel data. The instructions on preparing the data can be found on the websites.

Comment: please read my answer(comment) on "Bad Result And Evaluation From Giza++"